How to use text extraction strategy
I am stuck in itext7 custom strategy. My goal is to extract data from a PDF to a text file without losing the table format. My PDF has a different table structure, some table columns are horizontal and some table structure is vertical. How can I control this? My requirement is to turn the PDF table into text format without losing any table format. I am successful in turning the PDF turn into text format, but the PDF table loses its table format. Also, if column value is empty, how can I handle this situation?

"without losing any table format" - What do you mean by that? Tables in PDFs usually only are pieces of text somehow distributed more or less sparsely over an area, sometimes accompanied with lines or rectangles under or over those pieces. So what should be exported?

i am trying to say how i control reader in itext7 while convert pdf to text
for example if  i suppose
"line/ctrlnumber"  "RendproveId" these column in upperrow
39483757435        843765843    these value  in below but itext7 read data line by line how i control this
hope you understand!

iText reads data in the order in which it is drawn by the instructions in the content streams of the PDF. If you need it in a different order, you have to sort the data after you have received all of it.

i have already sort data from pdf but senarious is very complex after this then i think if i control i text7 to read data

Are your PDFs properly tagged? Then there is a good chance to extract the table structure based on the structure tree.
